# query to get statistic data from SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named total sales. In this table there are sales data like invoice date and branch name that sells the invoice and the quantity.

I am trying to make a query to get total sales for each branch in every single date and my code is below, but when I execute the code the query returns an error and I cannot determine the condition for every column.

my code :

```sql
SELECT invoice_date,
       COUNT(quantity) AS malqaStore,
       COUNT(quantity) AS tahliaStore
FROM total_sales
WHERE branche_name = 'branch1'
  AND branche_name = 'branch2'
GROUP BY invoice_date;
```

Comment: you need a case in the count and change the and clausule in the where for an or

Comment: Errr..... `branch_name='branch1' and branch_name='branch2'`. I think it is impossible.
Let's say use `branch_name=any('branch1','branch2')`

Comment: *"the query return the an error"* - What is the exact error?  What is the exact table definition?  (Best expressed here as a `CREATE TABLE` statement.)

Comment: I would be surprised if that query is returning an error. The only way I can see it would is if `branche_name` isn't a string based data type, and so `'branch1'` can't be (implicitly) converted to the correct data type.

Comment: i am trying to use any(' ',' ') but does not work and return that error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'branch1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, what you wanted should be

```
SELECT invoice_date,
       SUM(case when branche_name  = 'branch1' then quantity end) AS malqaStore,
       SUM(case when branche_name  = 'branch2' then quantity end) AS tahliaStore
FROM  total_sales
WHERE branche_name in ( 'branch1' , 'branch2' )
GROUP BY invoice_date;
```

You can use `branche_name in ( 'branch1' , 'branch2' )` or `WHERE branche_name = 'branch1' OR branche_name = 'branch2'` for filtering the 2 branches that you need.

As for the `malqaStore` and `tahliaStore`, my guess is you wanted a condition sum on the quantity for each of the branche_name